# Issues with n+1 queries in Rails Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm looking to assign past, current and future requests of a user to variables. He is my code:

```
@user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])

req = Request.where("user_id = ? OR item_id = ?",  @user.id, @user.item.first.id)

@next = req.where("start_datetime >= ?", Date.today).last(params[:offset].present? ? params[:offset] : "5" )

@current = req.where("start_datetime > ?", Date.today.beginning_of_day).where("end_datetime > ?", (Time.now - 30.minutes)).where(status: 'approved').order(:start_datetime).first || req.where("start_datetime > ?", Time.now).where(status: 'approved').order(:start_datetime).first

@past = req.where("start_datetime < ?", Date.today).last(5)
```

The issue is that I get hundreds of logs like below when doing this:

> CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1
>   LIMIT $2  [["id", 39], ["LIMIT", 1]]

I'm not sure why this is the case and how I can solve this?

Comment: this is active record cache, most likely current_user method. It doesnt hit db, so doesnt hurt performance

Comment: Oh ok so when it's written CACHE next to it, it can't hurt performance? It's still a mystery to me why I have hundreds of line of these for just a few queries. @apneadiving

Comment: did you define current_user yourself? In your context, I guess current user has id 39

Comment: I'm using this for an API, the current_user is the @user above.

Comment: weird because you get the user out of email, and the cached query is by id